# Did the metphor of double-edged sword originate in Psalms?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, hebrews, psalms, metaphor

We see at Hebrews 4:12:

> Indeed, the word of God is living and active, sharper than any two-edged sword, piercing until it divides soul from spirit, joints from marrow; it is able to judge the thoughts and intentions of the heart.

We also see at Psalms 149:6:

> Let the high praises of God be in their mouth, and a two-edged sword in their hand

My question is: did the writer of Hebrews have in mind the Psalms while using the metaphor of double-edged sword for the Word of God ? What do the teachings of Catholic Church speak about the possible origin of the metaphor used in Hebrews ?

Comment: Why do you think the sword in Ps 149:6 has anything to do with the scriptures? The following verses make it seem like a literal sword to defeat the enemies of Israel. Why do you think any particular origin is needed, rather than a sharp sword just being a natural metaphor?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to belong on, for example, [English StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Kadalikatt Joseph Sibichan - For what it's worth, Psalm 149:6 is cross-referenced in some Bibles to Hebrews 4:12. Yes, Psalm 149:7 goes on to link the double-edged sword to inflicting vengenance upon Israel's enemies, wheras in Hebrews 4:12 it is used as a metaphor to the power of God's Word.  I found interesting information on the Greek word translated "sword" in Hebrews which is also used to describe the blade wielded by Peter in Gethsemane (John 18:10) - but it's not from a Catholic perspective.  Care to edit your question to allow some input from others?

Comment: this is a very good question. As the Sword that pierced the Heart of Mary is the described like the Sword of Goliath in bible commentaries.The double-edge sword is a spiritual warfare in Ephesians6:17 it is the Sword of the Spirit and Jesus use the Word as a Sword to rebuked Satan in the desert.If your looking for Catholic view Fr.Calloway described rosary as "spiritual sword" in our hands so it is related Psalm149:6 that you quoted.Jesus release the Sword thru his mouth and Rosary is the Sword in our hand.